# Need to insert inline style

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I have this:

```
<td class="x188" ><a onclick="return false" class="xew" tabindex="-1" href="#" >xyz</a></td>
```

Is there is a way by which I can change the color of text "xyz" dynamically using some java script. so it should become as below:

```
<td class="x188" ><a onclick="return false" class="xew" tabindex="-1" href="#" style="color:#ffffff;">xyz</a></td>
```

Thanks in Advance,
Zubair

Comment: his is I want ...not sure why it did not printed <td class="x188" ><a onclick="return false" class="xew" tabindex="-1" href="#" style="color:#ffffff;">xyz</a></td>   Below is the current                                                                                 <td class="x188" ><a onclick="return false" class="xew" tabindex="-1" href="#">xyz</a></td>

Comment: hey @Zubair , to print code you have to click on the code icon in the text editor and then type your code, understand?

Comment: Thanks @ValterJunior

Comment: hey @Zubair .. can you mark as resolved/upvote if your question was answered, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this using pure javascript, you should do something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('xew')[0].style.color = 'red'
```

Take a look on this fiddle:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkjqt8xy/)